# Matplotlib's full_screen_toggle is not showing the full plot area

Tags: python, matplotlib, fullscreen, figure

I am trying to use `plt.imshow()` (though from what I have tried I get the same behavior with `plt.show()`) to create a fulscreen plot that will be interacted with using `plt.ginput()`. To best utilize the resolution, I would like to have the plot full screen to help with picking points. However, using:

```python
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Results in the window correctly going to full screen, but the plot is cutoff in that it seems that the plot itself within the window is too far to the bottom left.

I have tried using both `mng.full_screen_toggle()` and `mng.window.state('zoomed')` for the TkAgg backend on windows but both seem to have the same issue. Interestingly, if I first plot with either method and then toggle fullscreen with the f key, and then toggle back to full screen the problem fixes itself and I have the whole plot visbile with the window in full screen.

MWE:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 600)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Expected behavior:
[Full plot is visible within the figure window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLgCR.png)

actual behavior:
[Plot with lower right cutoff within fullscreen figure window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKgnh.png)

I am on Windows 11, Matplotlib v3.7.2, and Python v3.11.4. I do currently have a vertical monitor as my second display but the behavior persists even when it is unplugged.